# Ionic2 Local Notification not playing custom song

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building a simple notification/alarm app to play a notification at the time a user picks.  I'm building this in Ionic3, using the local-notification cordova plugin.  Everything worked fine while I used a default sound:  User picked a time, notification displayed at that time with sound and the text I wanted.  Now, I want to play a song when the notification goes off.  I put the path that goes to the song in the www folder, but now when the notification goes off at the specified time, the app crashes.  I'm not getting any error message when I use chrome://inspect/#devices so I can't even see what the error is, but it has to be something with the path to the file.  It is in fact the right path, spelled correctly, but maybe when using local-notification there's something quirky that I don't know about the paths for sound.  Here is how I have the notification defined:

```
let notification = {
            title: 'WAKE UP!!!!!',
            text: 'Get up and Go!!!!',
            at: alarmDate,
            sound: 'file://assets/default_tracks/the_number_of_the_beast.mp3'
        };
```

so I store this as a variable and then later call:

```
this.LocalNotifications.schedule(this.notifications);
```

Like I said, it worked with default sound, so I know it's not with the way I set anything up, it must be something with the path to the song.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: u want to play sound when notification goes off  ?? did u see that option in  plugin page ?

Comment: yes, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/   at the bottom it shows you the params.  sound is one of them, you need to supply the uri.

Comment: u want to play sound when notification goes off ?or   u want to play sound when notification goes on?

Comment: ah yes, I want to play a sound when the notification is triggered.  English is a confusing language.

Answer (score 1):

www folder is recreated every time when building

copy the sound file in `src/assets` folder,not in `www/assets`. so the file path will look like `src/assets/sound.mp3`

Configure sound for path Local notification

```
sound: 'file://assets/sound.mp3'
```

check www/assets folder after building.